# How to set time interval for showing last character in PasswordBox from WindowsPhone8.1

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, delay, passwordbox

It is possibility manage delay time for show last character in PasswordBox from WindowsPhone 8.1? As I see PasswordBox haven't any public properties for this.
Also PasswordBox is sealed so I can't create own control based on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

No.

(Answer must have at least 30 charakters.)